# VUE 3 Router - View not rendering

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to do multi pages VUE website. The problem is that my HomePage.vue is not rendering when I load `http://localhost:8080/home` ...
The only thing that is rendering is TEST and Click here! from the App.vue.

Do you have any idea why ?

I have no error in console or terminal. I can load but nothing happens.

HomePage.vue

```
<template>
    <p>This is HomePage !</p>
</template>
```

index.js (which is inside router folder)

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";
import Home from '../views/HomePage.vue'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },

]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

export default router
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1> TEST </h1>
    <a href="/home">
        <p>Click !</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

I already recreated a new VUE app in order to have no dependencies issues
Here is how I created my app:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli

// Creation of the Root Directory 

mkdir NOM_APP
cd NOM_APP

// Subfolders
mkdir server 

// At the Root folder (akksel/NOM_APP)
npm init -y
npm install concurrently --save-dev
```

modify package.json

```
"scripts": {
"client": "cd client && npm run serve",
"server": "cd server && node app.js",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
}
```

The `client` script navigates to the `client` folder and starts the Vue.js development server. The
`server` script navigates to the `server` folder and starts the Express.js server. The `dev` script
runs both the `client` and `server` scripts at the same time.

```
// At the Root folder (akksel/NOM_APP)
vue create client

//Choose default preset

cd server

// In the server folder, setup a new nodejs app
// Then install express 

npm install express --save
```

Create app. js in server dir. Paste the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I think you want it to render like an SSR app. So, you can follow these guides: [vue's createSSRApp()](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html), and [using Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html).

Otherwise, there's an simple approach by using [Nuxt](https://nuxt.com) or [Gridsome](https://gridsome.org).

Comment: Ok the issue was when I installed  vue-router. I've installed it in the root folder and not on the client directory.